# Ethernet network not starting on raspberrypi: DHCP6 CLIENT: Failed to set DUID: No medium found

Tags: systemd-networkd

I was trying to set up a static ip via systemd-networkd and it all worked, after I've removed my custom file and restarted the device both eth0 and wlan0 don't start.
I was hoping they would get their address from DHCP again, checking the debug logs I see:

```
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=12 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.10 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Bus bus-api-network: changing state HELLO → RUNNING
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus.Local destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/DBus/Local interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Local member=Connected cookie=4294967295 reply_cookie=0 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.10 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.10 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.10 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4 reply_cookie=2 signature=u error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Successfully acquired requested service name.
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.10 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=5 reply_cookie=3 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Match type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.login1',path='/org/freedesktop/login1',interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Manager',member='PrepareForSleep' successfully installed.
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: eth0: Link state is up-to-date
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: eth0: found matching network '/lib/systemd/network/80-wired.network'
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6' to '0'
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: eth0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/proxy_ndp' to '0'
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/use_tempaddr' to '0'
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra' to '0'
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Failed to set DUID-EN: No medium found
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: eth0: DHCP6 CLIENT: Failed to set DUID: No medium found
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: eth0: Failed
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: eth0: State changed: initialized -> failed
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=13 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 16 17:27:56 raspberrypi4 systemd-networkd[339]: DHCP CLIENT (0x0): STOPPED
```

however in the past the ipv6 address was successfully assigned. I wasn't able to find any reference to the `Failed to set DUID: No medium found` error

Comment: After further debugging it seems the issue is that /etc/machine-id is empty because our root filesystem isn't writable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turns out to be that we're using an overlayfs on /etc, which was overwriting the systemd generated `/etc/machine-id` with the default empty file as the tmpfs mounted by systemd on `/ets/machine-id` was being rewritten.

For that reason DHCP6 client wasn't able to set the DUID because `/etc/machine-id` was empty. I've fixed it by copying /etc/machine-id into the overlay partition if if doesn't exist making it persistent across reboots.

Comment: This solved my issue too. I was running on metal, but for some reason my `/etc/machine-id` file was missing. There was a `/etc/machine-id.old` there, so I copied it in place and now the network starts correctly. Thank you!